# React DOM manipulation vs CSS for responsive breakpoints?

Tags: css, reactjs, dom

Specifically for ReactJS and responsive frameworks that **show/hide** elements based on width like Bootstrap.

Because ReactJS has a virtual DOM I am presuming doing the DOM manipulation is faster and in the end a bit easier to debug because you are not trying to think which parts are `display:none` and there are less elements to debug.  It was also easier to me to think that way because of my programming background rather than CSS.

I haven't dealt with too much performance testing yet on ReactJS (that's a few chapters down) but what is better from an engineering standpoint.

Code wise it looks like this...

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.updateStatesBasedOnWindowSize =
      this.updateStatesBasedOnWindowSize.bind(this)
    this.state = {
        smallDeviceNavigation: false,
        sideNavVisible: false,
    }
}
componentWillMount() {
    this.updateStatesBasedOnWindowSize()
}
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateStatesBasedOnWindowSize)
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateStatesBasedOnWindowSize)
}

/**
 * This will trigger a state change based on the device size.
 */
updateStatesBasedOnWindowSize() {

    const w = window,
        d = document,
        documentElement = d.documentElement,
        body = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        width = w.innerWidth || 
                documentElement.clientWidth || body.clientWidth

    if (width >= 576) {
        if (this.state.smallDeviceNavigation) {
            this.setState({ smallDeviceNavigation: false })
        }
        if (!this.state.sideNavVisible) {
            this.setState({ sideNavVisible: true })
        }
    } else {
        if (!this.state.smallDeviceNavigation) {
            // Force hide the side 
            // nav if the smallDeviceNavigation was false before.
            this.setState({ sideNavVisible: false })
        }
        if (!this.state.smallDeviceNavigation) {
            this.setState({ smallDeviceNavigation: true })
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the components I just check `this.state` accordingly.  I get the advantage that I am dealing with the state based on a logical name rather than physical widths and breakpoints I am not dealing with.

Mind you this is for **show/hide** hence I emphasized it earlier.  Layouts based on CSS I just left alone and let bootstrap grid deal with it.  But menus and navs I did the DOM manipulation.

Comment: The `window` object is outside of the virtual dom, so show/hide via DOM computed properties causes [reflow and repaint](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a).